# How can I get data from a mongodb collection using pymongo in django using get method?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have one mongodb database and I have connected that db with pymongo in django. I am new to django, I am trying to get if the entered data present in the collection or not, if present return that record using get method

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
db_name = 'student_db'
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db_obj = client[db_name]
collection=db_obj['mongo_app_student']

@api_view(['GET'])
def test(request):
    data = request.data
    for x in collection.find():
        if data in x:
            print('entered a right value')
            return Response(data)
```

TypeError at /test
unhashable type: 'dict'

I am getting this error when i am trying to get the output in postman. please help

Answer (score 1):

First you Should use a POST request for that and since find() return a cursor, you're trying to iterate on a cursor. I'm not sure that's a good idea. And assuming `request.data` is a dict() try using `==` for comparison with `x`
Also Try casting what you get from mongo in a list like this :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
db_name = 'student_db'
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db_obj = client[db_name]
collection=db_obj['mongo_app_student']

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def test(request):
    response_data = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for x in list(collection.find()):
            if data == x:
                print('entered a right value')
                response_data = data
    return Response(response_data )
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Now I am getting this error:Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Yes the return statement shouldn' t be in the if statement. I've updated my answer above, try that out and let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks! this working pretty good but when running this server on postman, I am giving key=data, Value={'firstname':'Abburi'}. I am not getting anything like I have firstname:Abburi lastname:jagadeesh student_id:1 in my collection

Comment: Hum, are you trying to send a data like {"firstname":"Abburi", "lastname":"jagadeesh"} and you want your service to check if that exist in mongo ? if yes return that same data ?

Comment: Exactly if that present return me that doccument/row

Comment: So first for that you have to undersntand http verbs: Post -> send data, GET is only for retrieving. Check this out : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: And your service will have to change a bit, you should include POST in your api_view like `@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])`

Comment: And when using POSTMAN you should send a  post request with your data

Comment: one more thing, is below way is kinda right?:def testin(request):
    
    data = request.data
    myquery = { "firstname": data }
#    response_data = None
    for x in list(collection.find()):
        if myquery == x:
            print('entered a right value')
#            response_data = data
    return Response(data)

Comment: Let me know how it goes